# Why doesn't the MidiInputPort.flush() clear the buffer in Android?

Tags: android, midi

I am working with [android.media.midi](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/media/midi/package-summary.html) and I am sending a bunch of midi data to a MidiInputPort with a delay value like this:

```
long start = System.nanoTime();
if (messages != null)
{
    for (int i = 0; i < messages.length(); i++)
    {

        MidiNote note = MidiHelper.parseMessageForNote(messages.getString(i));
        if (note != null)
            {
                byte[] buffer = new byte[32];
                int numBytes = 0;
                int channel = 1; // MIDI channels 1-16 are encoded as 0-15.
                buffer[numBytes++] = (byte) (note.action + (channel - 1));
                buffer[numBytes++] = (byte) note.note;
                buffer[numBytes++] = (byte) note.velocity; 

                long delay = note.delay * 1000000;

                midiInputPort.send(buffer, 0, numBytes, start + delay);

                start = start + delay;
            }

     }

     midiInputPort.flush();
}
```

You'll notice that I call flush immediately after sending all the data (just trying to get flush() to work) but it has no effect. The data still gets sent to the Midi port as if I never called flush. The documentation is pretty clear and simple for this function. It says "If you want to cancel events that you have scheduled in the future then call flush()." Is there something about this that I am missing? Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Is the output stream still open?  Maybe the MIDI device you are sending the flush packet to doesn't support it?

Looking at the google source code, flush() calls MidiPortImpl.packFlush() which sends a single byte array of byte[1]=0x02 to the output stream as long as it is still open.

```
public void onFlush() throws IOException {
    synchronized (mBuffer) {
        if (mOutputStream == null) {
            throw new IOException("MidiInputPort is closed");
        }
        int length = MidiPortImpl.packFlush(mBuffer);
        mOutputStream.write(mBuffer, 0, length);
    }
}
```

https://android.googlesource.com/platform/frameworks/base/+/master/media/java/android/media/midi/MidiInputPort.java

https://android.googlesource.com/platform/frameworks/base/+/master/media/java/android/media/midi/MidiPortImpl.java